# Execute different Completables in succession

Tags: java, rx-java, reactivex

I am currently trying to achieve a specific outcome with the reactive extensions in java, however I am not able to do so, maybe someone of you can help me out.

```
firstCompletable
  .onErrorComplete(t -> specificErrorHandlingOne())
  .andThen(secondCompletable())
  .onErrorComplete(t -> specificErrorHandlingTwo())
  .andThen(thirdCompletable())
  .onErrorComplete(t -> specificErrorHandlingThree())
  .andThen(fourthCompletable())
  .onErrorComplete(t -> specificErrorHandlingFour())
  .subscribe(viewCallback::showSuccess)
```

However, when there is an error in, e.g., the secondCompletable, the specific error handling is being executed but then the other Completables are still being scheduled. I want the whole chain of Completables to stop executing if one of the Completables fails. How would I do that?

I already tried using doOnError instead, but this just ended up on n a stack trace of the specific error thrown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Completable.concat(
    completable1.doOnError(e -> {...}),
    completable2.doOnError(e -> {...}),
    completable3.doOnError(e -> {...}),
    completable4.doOnError(e -> {...})
).subscribe(action, errorConsumer);
```

- Completables will be subscribed to in specified order
- `action` will be invoked when all complete
- You can specify error handlers for each one (this is optional)
- Any error will break the pipeline and propagate to subscriber (`errorConsumer`)

Your original `andThen` chain shall also work but you need to replace `onErrorComplete`, which substitutes an error with completion, with `doOnError`, which just invokes specified action. Or just return `false` from your `specificErrorHandlingXxx()`.

Comment: Hey, looks good, but when e.g. the second Completable calls subscriber.onError(new Exception("Invalid phone number")), this makes my Android app crash. The doOnError handling method is being called, but then it crashes :(

Comment: @DavidBecher That's because error is propagated to subscriber, but subscriber does not handle it. I've updated the code to add such error consumer.

Comment: And if your snippet code was in a method (**P**) which returns `Completable` itself, and it has `Completable.fromAction` itself too ( that has two `Completable` methods inside(**C**) ), does the parent method(**P**) waits for those `Completable` child methods(**C**) to complete?

Comment: @Dr.jacky whether a method waits for something or not depends on threading. If things are executed on the same thread, then they are executed sequentially and in order, otherwise it is your job to synchronize.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("start");
    Completable c1 = Completable.fromAction(() -> printAndWait(1, 1));
    Completable c2 = Completable.fromAction(() -> printAndWait(2, 2));
    Completable c3 = Completable.fromObservable(Observable.timer(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS).concatWith(Observable.error(new RuntimeException())));
    Completable c4 = Completable.fromAction(() -> printAndWait(4, 2));

    c1.concatWith(c2).concatWith(c3).concatWith(c4).subscribe(e -> e.printStackTrace(), () -> System.out.println("done"));

    printAndWait(10, 10);//dont exit till program is completely executed

}

private static void printAndWait(int i, int j) {
    System.out.println(i);
    Observable.timer(j, TimeUnit.SECONDS).toBlocking().subscribe();//just add delay
}
```